# Words that mean ''to do or say something unexpectedly''?

Tags: word-meaning, word-request

What words are there that can mean you are doing or saying something unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a single word, 'to blurt out' is an expression for saying something unexpectedly, without thinking.

Answer (score 0):

> What words are there that can mean you are doing or saying something unexpectedly?

- spontaneously
- impromptu
- unplanned
- off the cuff
- randomly

Answer (score 0):

unforeseen, unanticipated, unpredicted, not bargained for, unlooked for, unhoped for, out of the blue, without warning, without notice.
chance, fortuitous, unplanned, serendipitous, adventitious.
sudden, abrupt, surprising, startling, astonishing, uncommon, abnormal, extraordinary.

1.surprised. adjective. having the feeling that you get when something unexpected happens.
2.shocked. adjective. very offended or embarrassed by something that you consider immoral.
2.amazed. adjective. very surprised.
3.speechless. adjective. ...
4.astonished. adjective. ...
5.astounded. adjective. ...
6.thunderstruck. adjective. ...
7.staggered. adjective.

Comment: If this is copy-pasted, which it seems to be although I can’t find any *exact* matches, could you at least list your source?

Comment: What about when you said something unexpectedly that it surprises you